# Update angularJs directive scope variable on change parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean

I am creating a directive in angularJS which will replace the element. I have a variable in parent scope which is bind to the element.

I want to update the directive scope variable on change the parent scope variable value.

The element is like below

```
<my-element attr-xyz="scope_variable"></myelement>
```

When I write the directive as below it give the updated value whenever scope variable update

```
.directive('myElement', function(){
    return function(scope, elem, attr){
        scope.$watch(attr.attrXyz, function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});
```

but when I write the same code like below it give the undefined value

```
return {
    scope: {attrXyz: '@'},
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller){
        scope.$watch(attr.attrXyz, function(value){
            console.log('value = '+value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A better way is to replace `link: function` with `controller:function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both way works. (Directive 1-2) http://plnkr.co/edit/2kJT1mkaORsS8RUOyZ0N?p=preview

However, if u introduce isoloated scope - 2nd way do not work. (Directive 3)

Then you can use $observe (Directive 4)

```
  attr.$observe('attrXyz', function(value){
      console.log('4: '+ value);
  });
```

Or you can define it in scope and use watch.

Comment: I have defined it in scope as scope:{attrXyz:'@'} and used watch but it was not working. I have replaced it with attr.$observe('attrXyz',function(value){}); now its working fine for me.

Comment: added to plunk directive5 with scope:{attrXyz:'@'} and watch

Comment: Okay, basically the changes of attr.attrXyz to attrXyz only. Thanks a log.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use only [`ng-attr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

```
<my-element ng-attr-xyz="scope_variable"></myelement>
```

Only use `$observe` and `$watch` if you really need to trigger a function/validation in the directive when this value changes, otherwise you are adding listener just for that and is more maintainable to use the attribute in the template.

Comment: Is ng-attr deprecated? I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: Seems to be deprecated, after version 1.3.20. [Here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/guide/directive) is the doc.

Comment: The functionality is still working, but reading on the [migration docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) seems to be no longer needed in angular 1.5. Correct me if i'm wrong